# Command prompt keep popping up

Tags: mingw, command-prompt

Whenever I am opening vs code, from the location: C:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\gcc1.exe
command prompt continuously popping up one after another from the same location. But there is noting written inside of it.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you using GCC 6? Current version is GCC 13. You can find a recent MinGW-w64 standalone build at https://winlibs.com